# Missing the following properties from type 'Map<string, Commune>': clear, delete, forEach, get

Tags: java, angular, typescript, swagger, openapi

A *REST* controller written in *Java* returns a `java.util.Map<String, Commune>` of French cities.

```java
/**
 * Obtenir la liste des communes.
 * @param anneeCOG Année de référence du Code Officiel Géographique.
 * @return Liste des communes.
 * @throws TechniqueException si un incident survient.
 */
@Operation(description = "Retourne les communes du Code Officiel Geographique en vigueur une année particulière sous forme de Map.")
@RequestMapping(value = "/communes", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiResponses(value = {
     @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Communes présentes sur le territoire cette année là, sous la forme d'une Map<String, Commune>."),
     @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Un incident est survenu durant l'extraction des communes.")
   }
)   
public Map<String, Commune> obtenirCommunes(
   @Parameter(name = "anneeCOG", description = "Année du Code Officiel Géographique.", example = "2019")
   @RequestParam(name="anneeCOG") int anneeCOG) throws TechniqueException {
   return this.cogService.obtenirCommunes(this.session, anneeCOG);
}
```

By the mean of *OpenApi (Swagger)* an `openapi.json` file is generated describing it, and on *Angular* side, a command :

```sh
npm run generate:api
```

generates a `cogController.service.ts` for this function :

```js
/**
 * Retourne les communes du Code Officiel Geographique en vigueur une année particulière sous forme de Map.
 * @param anneeCOG Année du Code Officiel Géographique.
 * @param observe set whether or not to return the data Observable as the body, response or events. defaults to returning the body.
 * @param reportProgress flag to report request and response progress.
 */
public obtenirCommunes(anneeCOG: number, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<{ [key: string]: Commune; }>;
public obtenirCommunes(anneeCOG: number, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<HttpResponse<{ [key: string]: Commune; }>>;
public obtenirCommunes(anneeCOG: number, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<HttpEvent<{ [key: string]: Commune; }>>;
public obtenirCommunes(anneeCOG: number, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<any> {
    if (anneeCOG === null || anneeCOG === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter anneeCOG was null or undefined when calling obtenirCommunes.');
    }

    let queryParameters = new HttpParams({encoder: this.encoder});
    if (anneeCOG !== undefined && anneeCOG !== null) {
        queryParameters = this.addToHttpParams(queryParameters,
        <any>anneeCOG, 'anneeCOG');
    }

    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

    let httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = options && options.httpHeaderAccept;
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected === undefined) {
        // to determine the Accept header
        const httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
            '*/*'
        ];
        httpHeaderAcceptSelected = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
    }
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected !== undefined) {
        headers = headers.set('Accept', httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
    }


    let responseType: 'text' | 'json' = 'json';
    if(httpHeaderAcceptSelected && httpHeaderAcceptSelected.startsWith('text')) {
        responseType = 'text';
    }

    return this.httpClient.get<{ [key: string]: Commune; }>(`${this.configuration.basePath}/cog/communes`,
        {
            params: queryParameters,
            responseType: <any>responseType,
            withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
            headers: headers,
            observe: observe,
            reportProgress: reportProgress
        }
    );
}
```

When I attempt to use this `obtenirCommunes(...)` method in a `subscribe` in a `communes.component.ts` component :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { CogControllerService } from './../../../openapi/api/cogController.service';
import { Commune } from 'openapi';

/**
 * Combobox en autocomplete des communes du COG.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'communes',
  templateUrl: './communes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./communes.component.css']
})
export class CommunesComponent implements OnInit {
  /** Année du Code Officiel Géographique. */
  @Input()
  anneeCOG: number;

  /** Locale du tri des communes */
  @Input()
  locale: string = "fr_FR";

  /** Liste des communes ordonnées par locale */
  communes: Commune[];

  /** Liste des communes sous forme de Map, pour la vérification rapide de validité */
  verificationCommunes: Map<string,Commune>;

  /** Code commune sélectionné. */
  codeCommune: string = null;

  /** Commune sélectionnée. */
  commune: Commune = null;

  /**
   * Construire une instance du composant.
   * @param cogService Service REST d'accès au Code Officiel Géographique.
   */
  constructor(private readonly cogService: CogControllerService) { }

  /**
   * Renvoyer le code commune de la commune sélectionnée.
   */
  public getCodeCommune(): string {
    return this.codeCommune;
  }

  /**
   * Renvoyer la commune sélectionée.
   */
  public getCommune() : Commune {
    return this.commune;
  }

  /**
   * Déterminer si une commune a été sélectionnée.
   */
  public hasCommuneSelected() : boolean {
    return !this.codeCommune;
  }

  /**
   * Réaction à l'initialisation du composant : 
   * Lire les communes triées par locale, et sous forme de Map indexée par codeCommune.
   */
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Vérification du paramètre d'appel (année)
    if (this.anneeCOG < 2019 || this.anneeCOG >= 2100) {
      let message = "L'année du code officiel géographique "+ this.anneeCOG + " n'est pas valide : choissez-là à partir de 2019.";
      console.log(message);
      return;
    }

    this.cogService.obtenirCommunes(this.anneeCOG).subscribe(data => {
      this.verificationCommunes = data;
    });

    this.cogService.obtenirCommunesTriParLocale(this.anneeCOG, this.locale).subscribe(data => {
      this.communes = data;
    });
  }
```

I receive this message :

```
error TS2740: Type '{ [key: string]: Commune; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<string, Commune>': clear, delete, forEach, get, and 8 more.

75       this.verificationCommunes = data;
```

involving the function :

```js
this.cogService.obtenirCommunes(this.anneeCOG).subscribe(data => {
   this.verificationCommunes = data;
});
```

What is happening, and how should I correct my component `communes.component.ts` ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the Typescript error is pretty explanatory.

The data produced by the `Observable` returned by `obtenirCommunes()` is of type `{ [key: string]: Commune; }`, but your `this.verificationCommunes` variable is of type `Map<string, Commune>` and Typescript tells you that in order to assign to this variable you need to have some mandatory methods on the object you want to assign.

The reason you don’t have these methods is because there is no mapping done to transform the data you receive from the backend — which is JSON converted to a plain old Javascript object, by default — to an **instance** of `Map`.
If you want to assign to `Map`, you need to construct a `Map` :

```js
const map: Map<string, Commune> = new Map();
map.set("Paris", commune);
...
```

Another question you may want to ask yourself is: do you really need a `Map`?

Comment: Then `obtenirCommunes()` should have returned an Observable of `Map<string, Commune>` instead of a `{ string, Commune }` single item (if I understand you well), because the _Java_ method returns a `Map<String, Commune>` that is a collection.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan No, these are two different languages, and Typescript can’t possibly know what object type you used in Java. All your frontend sees when it queries your API is your Java Map serialized to JSON :

`{"key1": {"name": "Paris", "zipCode": 75000}, "key2": {}, ...}`
Then, it converts this JSON to a simple Javascript object and that’s all.

The Javascript `Map` type is a more complex object and you need to construct it explicitly if you want to use the methods associated with it.